# Reading product info from .xml and write it to another .xml

Tags: c#, xml, dom

A have a very simple product list in XML. I need to read that products and write the ones with stack smaller or equal to 5 to another XML file.

Sample from first XML file:

```
<product id="1">
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <price>12</price>
    <stack>10</stack>
</product>
<product id="2">
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <price>10</price>
    <stack>10</stack>
</product>
<product id="3">
    <name>Name 3</name>
    <price>8</price>
    <stack>10</stack>
</product>
```

I tried to achieve my goal like this:

```
public void FilterProducts(string input, string output)
    {
        if (input != null)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load(input);

            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

            XmlNodeList nameList = root.GetElementsByTagName("name");
            XmlNodeList priceList = root.GetElementsByTagName("price");
            XmlNodeList stackList = root.GetElementsByTagName("stack");

            for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
            {
                double quantityOnStack = Convert.ToDouble(stackList[i].InnerText);

                if (quantityOnStack >= 5)
                {
                    XmlElement product= doc.CreateElement("product");
                    product.SetAttribute("id", (i + 1).ToString());

                    XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("name");
                    name.InnerText = nameList[i].InnerText;
                    product.AppendChild(name);

                    XmlElement price = doc.CreateElement("price");
                    price.InnerText = priceList[i].InnerText;
                    product.AppendChild(price);

                    XmlElement stack = doc.CreateElement("stack");
                    stack.InnerText = stackList[i].InnerText;
                    product.AppendChild(stack);


                    XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(output, null);
                    tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    doc.WriteContentTo(tw);

                    tw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
```

What happens is that the second XML file, which should be filtered, is exatly the same as first one. So basically the if statement is not working somehow. I also have products with stack under 5 in the list. Any tips?

Comment: Have you try using the VS debugger to see the value of `quantityOnStack`? Does it always have the expected value?

Comment: I checked it now. The values of stack are always correct, and the if statement is skipped aswell. "If statement" works as intended too. No idea where the catch is in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("products.xml");

        var products = from p in doc.Descendants("product")
                       where Double.Parse(p.Element("stack").Value) <= 5
                       select p;

        XDocument output = new XDocument();
        XElement root = new XElement("root");
        output.Add(root);
        foreach(var e in products)
        {
            root.Add(e);
        }

        output.Save("found.xml");
```

Using XmlDocument

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("products.xml");

        XmlNodeList products = doc.GetElementsByTagName("product");

        XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = output.CreateElement("root");
        output.AppendChild(root);
        foreach(XmlNode e in products)
        {
            if (Double.Parse(e.ChildNodes[2].InnerText) <= 5)
            {
                XmlNode imported = output.ImportNode(e, true);
                root.AppendChild(imported);
            }
        }

        output.Save("found.xml");
```

Comment: This would probably work. But because this is a school assignment, the problem is required to be solved in DOM. Appreciate the help tho.

Answer (score 1):

**smaller** or equal to 5

Okay...

```
if (quantityOnStack >= 5)
```

Erm...

```
<stack>10</stack>
```

Your if-statement returns true for `quantityOnStack` **greater than or equal** to 5. Every `stack` in each `product` in your example XML is greater than 5, so of course the resulting XML is all of the above.

Did you mean to write:

```
if (quantityOnStack <= 5)
```

Comment: Smaller or higher is not the point here. There should only be half of the products in the new XML file, however you turn it. And this is just a sample of the list. There are many more products in there, both with higher and lower stack then 5. Apologies for not posting more accurate XML example.

Comment: @cvenko Please explain to me why you think your if-statement should be checking if `quantityOnStack` is *greater* than or equal to 5.

Comment: It should be checking quantity, because I need to create 2 new XMl files from the original one. One with products that have higher or equal stack to 5, and other products that have lower stack.

Answer (score 0):

First you load your input document in the `doc` variable

`doc.Load(input);`

Then you write the doc element to the file

`doc.WriteContentTo(tw);`

You're basically writing your input document directly in your output file.

You need to create a second XmlDocument in which you will add your filtered list of product and then use the Save method to save the list to the output file

```
public void FilterProducts(string input, string output)
{
    if (input != null)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(input);

        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNodeList nameList = root.GetElementsByTagName("name");
        XmlNodeList priceList = root.GetElementsByTagName("price");
        XmlNodeList stackList = root.GetElementsByTagName("stack");

        XmlDocument outputDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement products = outputDoc.CreateElement("products");
        outputDoc.AppendChild(products);

        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
        {
            double quantityOnStack = Convert.ToDouble(stackList[i].InnerText);

            if (quantityOnStack >= 5)
            {
                XmlElement product= outputDoc.CreateElement("product");
                product.SetAttribute("id", (i + 1).ToString());

                XmlElement name = outputDoc.CreateElement("name");
                name.InnerText = nameList[i].InnerText;
                product.AppendChild(name);

                XmlElement price = outputDoc.CreateElement("price");
                price.InnerText = priceList[i].InnerText;
                product.AppendChild(price);

                XmlElement stack = outputDoc.CreateElement("stack");
                stack.InnerText = stackList[i].InnerText;
                product.AppendChild(stack);

                products.AppendChild(product);

            }
        }
        outputDoc.Save(output);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working now for products with stack greater or equal to 5. But if i change if statement to less then 5, the new XML file is not even created (there are products with stack less than 5 in the original list tho).